# Create user in admin group via command line, but not O.S Language dependency

Tags: windows, batch-file, operating-system

i need create user in admin group via command line, but not O.S Language dependency:

the problem is that some machine have spanish lengueage other english....

and group must be called `Administradores` or `Administrators`

```
net user prueba2 123456 /add
net localgroup Administradores prueba2 /add

pause
```

How can I make this batch script work on any O.S

Comment: If you run the `NET LOCALGROUP` command with no arguments it will list all the local groups.  Use the `FIND` or `FINDSTR` commands to test for the existence or even capture the output with a `FOR /F` command and set the group name to a variable.

Comment: PowerShell: `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Group -Filter "Domain='$env:COMPUTERNAME' AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'").Name`

Comment: As an aside: I would recommend migrating to PowerShell, as it is object-oriented, has first-class support for WMI and ADSI, and much, much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a batch file example which runs your two commands, retrieving the required `LocalGroup` name using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic):

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%net.exe User prueba2 123456 /Add
@For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Group Where SID^="S-1-5-32-544" Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL')Do @%__AppDir__%net.exe LocalGroup %%G prueba2 /Add
```

If one or more of your systems are Windows 7, there's a potential issue with the example above, *(the required `xsl` file isn't, by default, located in the correct directory)*. The following modification should hopefully take care of that issue, *and should still work as intended on the other WMIC supported Operating Systems*:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%net.exe User prueba2 123456 /Add
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe /R %__AppDir__% mof.xsl 2^>NUL')Do @For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%H In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Group Where SID^="S-1-5-32-544" Get Name /Format:"%%G" 2^>NUL')Do @%__AppDir__%net.exe LocalGroup %%H prueba2 /Add
```

Please remember to change the two instances of your user name and your password as needed. It is likely that this script needs to run by an account with sufficient permissions to create users.